# Use same component for different route in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to use the same component for the different routes
**i.e - I have 2 routes**

1. http://example.com/users/39
2. http://example.com/users/39/58

Now I want to render the same component if a user visits one of the above route. I tried the below code and it's working fine for me, but it's not the proper solution. Is there any way to achieve in a single route?

```
<script>
{
    path: ':id',
    component: () => import('@/views/Users')
},
{
    path: ':id/:user_id',
    component: () => import('@/views/Users')
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare an optional argument:

```
{
    path: '/users/:id/:user_id?',
    component: () => import('@/views/Users')
}
```

This will work for `/users/39` and `/users/39/58`